# A way to generate a report for Serenity BDD test stability over time?

Tags: automation, software-testing, reporting, jenkins, maven

I have a suite of Webdriver w Serenity BDD tests that is being expanded by all developers, I've noticed that some tests fail randomly even when none of the components change meaning that they've been poorly coded and are flaky. I could go talk to the team that added them, that's not a long term solution, I'd still have to constantly monitor failed test runs and the cycle continues. Best solution is to keep track of test failure rates over time so we can learn which parts of the website or which tests are flaky, then we can target the thing that needs improvement.

How do I generate a report that will show me the pass/failure rate of my tests over time? Is there a maven or jenkins plugin, maybe a java library?